# How would the time complexity change from brute force to recursion solution?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, big-o, brute-force, divide-and-conquer

This is a problem I am working on [image]

I implemented a brute force solution and a divide and conquer(recursive) solution. They both work with this input(from post 1 to 4)

For the brute force solution, what I did was generate all subsets of {1,2,3,4}, iterate through all the subsets and check only the ones that contained 1 and 4. I know that my brute force solution would run in  *O(2<sup>n</sup>)* time because there are mathematically *2<sup>n</sup>* subsets and I have to iterate over all of them.

For my recursive solution. what I did was break this problem down so that the only solutions that are generated/will be checked will be ones that contain 1 and 4. For example, from 1 you can go to 2,3,4 and if you go to 2, you can go to 3,4, and so on... till 4 is reached.

After analyzing both algorithms, I realized the only difference is that the divide and conquer wouldn't even check the subsets that didn't have 1 and 4 but the brute force would, say {2,3}. How would this difference affect the time complexity of the recursive algorithm. Would the recursive algorithm also run in *O(2<sup>n</sup>)* or something less because it checks less subsets?

Comment: Seems like classic problem for Dynamic Programming, since the problem have optimal substructure. (or just reduce the problem to a DAG, and run shortest path problem algorithm).

Comment: belongs on http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's perfectly on topic here as well, under the algorithm tag. It asks how to solve a problem, that can be computed in any programming language.

Comment: @amit yeah dynamic programming is the next step. I think this is more of a progression to help you see the difference between recursion, brute force and dynamic

Comment: @amit do you know what the runtime would be? Rest of the answers are unclear/ haven't addressed that.

Answer (score 0):

Extra step for optimisation in recursive is using memoization. Reasoning goes -  once you get and stop at post x it is always same cost till end, no matter where are you coming from.
It turns out that all it is required is array holding at index i lowest price to get to end. This can be populated going right to left in O(n²)time.

Comment: It doesn't ask how to optimize it, it asks what will be the run time of the divide and conquer approach.

Answer (score 0):

There exists a straightforward dynamic programming solution.

Consider each successively longer optimum canoe journey as the function of some shorter optimum canoe journey. I.e., the cheapest way to travel to post 4 is the cheapest way to travel to post 3 plus the best decision for the interval 3 to 4. Then consider the cheapest way to reach post 5 as a function of the previously calculated cheapest way to visit post 4.

Implement this recursion in code and your solution should be O(n^2), similar to the perennial CLRS favorite: the rod-cutting problem: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-13-cutting-a-rod/

The divide-and-conquer approach would check singletons at which a rental was initiated, and then "merge" steps would optimize across the new doubleton/4ton/etc. It'll be much better than O(2^n) because you won't be recalculating all possibilities for every subpath, but it's a greedy algorithm--it makes an assumption about the answer before it has perfect information about the answer.

If you assume that the optimum decision occurs during some merge step of the subsets, you will necessarily miss cases where renting a boat at 1 and returning it at n is the best solution, but the runtime is O(n log n). But, if you check the input and optimize for every merge, you're back at O(2^n).

Comment: The question asks about something very specific, and not how to solve it. It does not answer the question, which is about the run time of the divide and conquer approach

Comment: Editing to reflect that.

Comment: @quietudecircuit  Can you give an example in which this fails? I agree this is greedy cause you're searching for the least cost but I don't see a situation where this fails - you're going through all the possible paths.

Comment: Edited with more explanation.

Comment: With regards to " if you check the input and optimize for every merge", did I do that in the divide and conquer approach? Does input just refer to each possible path?